# rails update with checkbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-update, checkboxlist

I want in my restaurant application to change the status of "preparated" to "deliverated" with a checkbox list but when doing the reload of the view where it does not make any changes, and logically the query is well I do not understand which is the problem.
[`View of the application`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7pjm.jpg)

Orderdish.rb

```
class Orderdish < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to  :order
    belongs_to     :dish


    def self.orders_waiter waiter
        orders_waiter=Orderdish.all.joins({:order => :table},:dish).select("orderdishes.*,orderdishes.state as status,orderdishes.id as id, dishes.*, dishes.speciality_id as speciality_id, tables.*, orders.*, orders.created_at as order_created, tables.*, tables.waiter_id as waiter_id").where("waiter_id = ?", waiter.id).where("orderdishes.state = ?", "preparated").order("order_created ASC")
        return orders_waiter

    end
end
```

Controller

```
  def orderWaiter
     @ordersWaiter = Orderdish.orders_waiter current_waiter
     @ordersWaiter = @ordersWaiter.paginate(:page => 1, :per_page => 12)
  end

   def deliverated
     puts Orderdish.where(id: params[:orderdishes_ids]).update_all state: "deliverated"
     redirect_to :orderWaiter

  end
```

Routes

```
resources :order_views do
    collection do
      put :preparated
      put :deliverated
    end
  end

  get 'orderWaiter'  => 'order_views#orderWaiter'
```

View

```
<div class="aboutUs">
    <%= form_tag deliverated_order_views_path, method: :put do %>
    <table class="table table-inverse">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>  </th>
          <th>Created </th>
          <th>Table </th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Specification</th>
          <th>Quantity</th>
          <th>State</th>

          <th colspan="3"></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <% @ordersWaiter.each do |orderwaiter| %>
          <tr>
            <td><%= check_box_tag "orderdishes_ids[]", orderwaiter.id %></td>
            <td><%= orderwaiter.order_created.to_time.strftime('%B %e at %l:%M %p') %></td>
            <td><%= orderwaiter.number %></td>
            <td><%= orderwaiter.name %></td>
            <td><%= orderwaiter.specification %></td>
            <td><%= orderwaiter.quantity %></td>
            <td><%= orderwaiter.status %></td>

          </tr>
        <% end %>

      </tbody>
    </table>


    <%= submit_tag "Deliverated" %>

  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: You mean prepared and delived?

Comment: Also the use of a checkbox seems wrong. A dish can't be delivered if its not prepared.

Comment: What error u getting??

Comment: does not modify the field and does not perform the new query when reloading the orderWaiter page again